# SQL order by time of day when spanning 2 days

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Title might be quite cryptic but here's my question.

I have a table of events for a day (itinerary). Each entry (visit museum, for example) has slot_start and slot_end time columns. This is in 24hr format so 13:00:00 - 15:00:00 for example.

I want to order these by slot_start asc but I could have an entry for "go to bar/club" with slot_start 00:00:00 ie. midnight which would get ordered first which would be the correct order but since this is actually a new day I want it to come after the museum.

There is no specific date for these. they are only constrained by their slot times and thought as events for a day.

Does anyone have experience of this kind of set up? Or can anyone suggest a different way of setting the time of each 'event'? I guess I might have to introduce some element of which day it is in terms of day 1, day 2...

Comment: What dbms? SQL is a language.

Comment: Yeah I know, using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can order by multiple columns by using:

```
ORDER BY Day, Time
```

Answer (score 0):

so "00:00:00" means after the museum and if they had entered the club at 00:01:00? or 00:01:00?

You would need a "day" on your table to control that.

A very "ugly" solution to your problem would be something like this:

first choose a "limit" to consider records always "older", lets say 3AM so every record before 3 would be considered "after" everything else. Then do:

```
select * 
from your_table 
where slot_start > '03:00:00'
order by slot_start 

union

select * 
from your_table 
where slot_start < '03:00:00'  and slot_start > '00:00:00'
order by slot_start
```

but again, this is not a good solution. Ideally you need a "day" control on your table

Comment: Wouldn't `ORDER BY (slot_start NOT BETWEEN '00:00:01' AND '02:59:59') DESC, slot_start ASC` be easier then using `union`?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use start_unix and duration.

- start_unix is the unix_timestamp when the event is starting
- duration is simply the duration
- end_unix = (start_unix + duration)

That's an easy way to achieve full control of these issues.

A sinful solution for you might be to set these times who pass over midnight to be for example 25:00:00 (01:00:00) and when you show them you do a `SELECT MOD(slot_start, 24) AS slot_start_mod` and `ORDER BY slot_start`.

Answer (score 0):

here is an Idea you can subtract 1 min from actual Slot_start time just for sorting (but it is recommended to use Date Column in your table).

```
Select * from Table order by dateadd(minute,-1,TIME)
```

dateadd function adds (-1) minute to TIME column just to order them